# How to compile COBOL 85 program on

Tags: cobol

So here is the problem:
 Recently someone bought a new PC for server to replace an older dating from before 1985 (i wonder how it is possible to work daily from then) .
He wants to put there the old COBOL software and he isnt willing in any means to rewrite it to something better..

So is there any compiler for 1985 cobol? For nowadays red hat linux? Googling it found opencobol and other few but all converted the code to c... Seems too compilacted too me..
**UPDATE AS REQUESTED**
AIX was the old system

Comment: What sort of platform is the old COBOL program running on? Maybe you could just virtualize the old environment...

Comment: @ChristopheD: I second that. I've seen PDP/RSX11M virtual machines run on Windows boxes for example

Comment: What's complicated about converting to C? I'm sure you can have a Makefile that makes it all transparent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's the problem with converting the COBOL to C and then compiling?  As long as it works.  Early C++ environments were implemented in the same way:  they converted the C++ to C, and then invoked the C compiler.

Converting the COBOL to C allows them to use high-level abstractions that implement the COBOL equivalents in C.  They can leverage the standard C libraries, and also convert the COBOL data access code into calls to widely available databases like MySQL.  Finally, converting to C and then compiling leverages the vast amount of development effort that went into code generation.  Were they to try compiling directly to object code, they'd have to generate the intermediate code expected by the GNU compiler subsystem, or they'd have to go directly to object code.  Either one of those would be much more complicated than converting to C, meaning that the likelihood of bugs in the COBOL compiler would be much higher.

From where I sit, I'd say OpenCOBOL is worth looking into.  Note that they say they implement "a substantial part of the COBOL 85 and COBOL 2002 standards."  You probably want to make sure that they implement the parts that you need.

I would also suggest that you look into [TinyCOBOL](http://tiny-cobol.sourceforge.net/index.php).

Comment: By converting you mean manually or automatically via OpenCobol ?

Comment: Automatically by OpenCOBOL.  Understand that it doesn't convert and output C code for you to maintain.  Rather, the compilation process is that OpenCOBOL "compiles" the COBOL to C, and then calls the GNU C compiler to compile the C code.  You're still able to modify the COBOL and re-compile.

Comment: @Parhs... This is the best advice so far... I would give serious consideration
to OpenCobol as I understand it is more COBOL-85 compliant than TinyCobol.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention when the application, or AIX was last updated. If these were updated in the last few years, you may be able to port the application, without re-compiling. You should check to see what COBOL compiler was used originally, e.g IBM, RM/COBOL, AcuCOBOL, etc.  It might be possible to buy a run-time only version (will execute, but not compile), which would be cheaper than buying a compiler.

Comment: It was RM-COBOL ..It needed many corrections for OpenCobol to run.

Answer (score 0):

A company called [Micro Focus](http://microfocus.com/) make a cobol compiler for Windows  but I can assure you it is not cheap at all!

Answer (score 0):

Standard method for doing this is called migrating and involves a number of steps including converting source file to a textfile format or a filetype compatible with the target computer, using an approved method of converting to a file and writing to magtape with compatible recording method of Phase encoding or to disk or other data medium possibly in the ASN.xx mode, transferring to the new computer to then read in the file (through ASN.yy) and store it in a native or import file format, then either use a utility to convert it to the sourcefile format or by running the program development environment to access the native text file or import file and saving the content as a native sourcefile. Perform manual checks and amendments to the source or script code and then compile the program and repeat alterations until a working version is achieved. Create test data files on the new computer and create a new jobfile or macro to run the job in the development environment. When fully tested the program can be run live using data files and live macros or jobfiles migrated over from the old system or newly created in more or less the same way as bringing over the source code. An important point is that the live data must be read into a specialized data takeon or loading program to achieve a populated database before any new transactions occur in the case of a structured datafile being necessary. When moving from AIX or other versions of Unix to an entirely different operating system the characters for end of line and linefeed and end of record may need specific conversion if they are not handled by a file format convertor or exporter utility.